# I want to build a Frequency Modulation circuit

Tags: frequency, design, communication, modulation

Does anyone have a simple circuit design that can implement Frequency Modulation or even Amplitude Modulation?

Comment: Google for "FM bug" and "AM bug". You will find lots of 1 or 2 transistor circuits. Here is good [page](http://darkliferadio.proboards.com/index.cgi?board=tech&action=print&thread=15) with lots of options.

Comment: Question was very much simpler so can you provide any specifications of circuit which you asked?  and you will get better votes and answers if you provide what you have tried before asking an question.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of ways to do these things.  One easy way to think about amplitude modulation is to make a oscillator, then have another signal vary its power supply.  You don't say what you want to modulate with what kind of signal, but amplitude modulating a square wave is particularly easy.  If you want the carrier to be a sine wave, then you can filter after the modulation to reduce the harmonics.  If you are modulating at a fixed carrier frequency, then a resonant output filter will get rid of most of the harmonics.

FM modulation is also easy, but a little harder to conceptualize if you're not fluent with electronics.  There are chips that do this, called *voltage controller oscillators*, or VCOs for short.  One way you can do this yourself is to note that a capacitor charges up more quickly thru a resistor when the voltage at the other end of the resistor is higher.  You can make a oscillator out of this, where the period is set by how fast a capacitor charges up and discharges.  The more current you supply for the capacitor to do this, the faster the oscillator will run.  The 555 timer is based on this principle of charging and then discharing a capacitor to different theshold voltages.  With a little cleverness, you can have a modulation signal change how fast the capacitor is charged and discharged, which in turn effects the oscillator frequency.

This can be done digitally too.  For FM, use a hardware PWM generator built into a micro, and adjust its period based on the modulation signal.  For AM, a hybrid approach is possible.  Many D/A converters are ratiometric to some reference signal.  This means the output is really the product of the analog reference voltage and the digital value.  This can be used to perform AM.  If the signals are slow enough, you can compute the final output and write that to a fixed D/A.

There are many other ways too, both for AM and FM.  If you explain more specifically what you are trying to do, a more specific answer is possible.

Answer (score 3):

We did this last semester as part of "Systems and Signals" course:

The simple square wave described by Olin is done by means of a "Chopper Circuit". The chopper circuit is just EE speak for a on/off modulator. We used the National Semiconductor CD4066. The chopper circuit is on the left:

[image]

- **[A]** Input of the message signal
- **[B]** Input of the modulating signal (carrier)
- **[C]** Modulated output

For our specific experiment the carrier wave was a 15kHz square wave at 50% duty cycle and the message signal a 100Hz sine wave.

Using these signals gives you the following output (top signal):

[image]

This is however not yet amplitude modulation. For that we used a butterworth bandpass filter tuned for 15kHz (same as the carrier). The circuit can be seen of the right. This filters out unwanted harmonics as Olin said. Once through the bandbass filter by connecting **[C]** to **[D]**, the bottom signal is measured at output **[E]**

You now have a form of AM modulation known as DSB-SC ([Double-SideBand - Supressed Carrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-sideband_suppressed-carrier_transmission)). It is however not the AM you know as transmitted for radio stations. For that, DSB-LC (Large Carrier) is used. To generate a LC signal, a voltage offset is added to the carrier signal. The final DSB-LC modulated signal is then obtained:

[image]

You now have your AM modulated signal. It doesn't take much more effort to implement FM although I don't have the pretty graphs to show yet. If you are interested I can add the FM as well.